# Exhibiting an adversary to prove a boolean function is evasive

Tags: boolean-functions

I'm trying to collect examples of exhibiting an adversary to prove that a Boolean function is evasive. I know of several examples of graph properties for which adversary methods have been used, i.e. graph connectedness and containing a triangle, however I'm hoping to find other interesting examples.

Comment: Google for "Lecture Notes on Evasiveness of Graph Properties".

Comment: More precisely: see http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0205031 for Neal Young's notes from a lecture course given by László Lovász at Princeton in 1990.